# Uncaught Error: Type Geolocation does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, geolocation

I am making an ionic/angular project where I need to use a geolocation plugin on one of the pages. Everything is compiling but when I run localhost:8200 I keep getting the error above

**This is my app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/Storage';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [IonicStorageModule, HttpClientModule, BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [Geolocation, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**and here is the plugin page.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
    import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-plugin',
      templateUrl: './plugin.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./plugin.page.scss'],
    })
    export class PluginPage {
      long:any;
      lat:any;
      constructor(private geolocation:Geolocation) { }
    
      GPS(){
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
          this.lat = resp.coords.latitude
          this.long = resp.coords.longitude
         }).catch((error) => {
           console.log('Error getting location', error);
         });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing this:
`npm i --save @ionic-native/geolocation@5.0.0-beta.14`
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation does not work on Browser. Run the app on your phone, see if you get the error.